# Unable to trigger notebook extension post installation

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have installed the following extension on an AI notebook on GCP. The installation went through with:

```
sudo jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
```

It shows up as installed in the extensions pane on the left. However I am uncertain how to trigger the extension to work as it does not appear even after restarting the machine and the browser.

Are there additional steps I need to perform?

Answer (score 0):

Install the extension (can be done via terminal):

```
sudo jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/toc
```

[optional] Check that the extension has been properly installed with:

```
jupyter labextension list
```

Restart notebook and browser:

```
sudo service jupyter restart

restart the browser
```

To trigger a comment you need to use a markdown cell and '# title' (notice the space between hashtag and text)